# Subset a dataframe using a list to define the input column

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe matrix that I want to run multiple plots and summaries on with one of my variable names being input via a list.

Example:
I have a dataframe called Species:

```
ID  Spp1    Spp2    Spp3    Spp4
M   Null    827     647     331
M   721     3974    Null    143
F   1737    494     96      276
M   Null    9304    Null    7435
F   Null    Null    Null    Null
F   262     331     158     1223
F   293     771     647     3101
```

I want a dataframe that filters the columns via the list:

```
ID  Spp1    Spp2    Spp3    Spp4
M   721     3974    Null    143
F   1737    494     96      276
F   262     331     158     1223
F   293     771     647     3101
```

In the example below, I want to subset my table within a for loop based on the in.List providing the the selection field inSpp. I have tried building an expression 1st and stripping off the ", filters to extract NA from the field of interest. Nothing I have tried allows me to set a variable as input for the subset or boxplot lines. How do I use a variable for inputs?

The goal is something where plotSpecies <- subset(Species, inSpp >= 1) = plotSpecies <- subset(Species, Spp1 >= 1)

```
in.List <- c(“Spp1”, “Spp2”, “Spp3”, “Spp4”)

for(inSpp in in.List){

    plotSpecies <- subset(Species, inSpp >= 1) 
    boxplot(inSpp~ID, data=plotSpecies, id.method="y", do.conf=TRUE, notch=TRUE, top=TRUE, main=inSpp)

}
```

Comment: I'm confused. You first describe summarize a frame from 7 rows to 4, but you don't talk about the aggregation or reduction steps needed. Then you ask about plotting each column (as defined in `in.List`), which doesn't even use this new data (nor is the data really big enough to justify boxplots). Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm confused by you question.  I don't ask about summarizing the data frame with 7 rows, my question is how to subset a dataframe when part of the subset statement is a variable assigned from a list.

Comment: Okay, I think I see ... your second frame is not a reduction, it is your second list. I read it wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both functions in your `for` loop, `subset()` and `boxplot()`, use "non-standard evaluation", and thus expect unquoted variable names. But in the loop, `inSpp` variable evaluates to a character string. You can use one of two ways to get around this, either using `[[` or replacing `inSpp` with `eval(as.name(inSpp))`, as below:

```
for (inSpp in in.List) {
  plotSpecies <- subset(Species, Species[[inSpp]] >= 1) 
  boxplot(plotSpecies[[inSpp]] ~ plotSpecies$ID, 
          id.method = "y", do.conf = TRUE, notch = TRUE, top = TRUE, 
          main = inSpp)
}

for (inSpp in in.List) {
  plotSpecies <- subset(Species, eval(as.name(inSpp)) >= 1) 
  boxplot(eval(as.name(inSpp)) ~ ID, data = plotSpecies,
          id.method = "y", do.conf = TRUE, notch = TRUE, top = TRUE, 
          main = inSpp)
}
```

Comment: Arun, thank you very much.  That was exactly what I was after.  I know how to do this in Python but the syntax and structure in R is still a learning curve for me. Really should take a class in R sometime.